# Склонировать ветку в свой проект

Tags: android, git, github

Есть проект, на котором работаю по большей части на работе.

Есть несколько сделанных коммитов, которые я запушил на сервер.
Сейчас хочу перенести ветку на свою домашнюю машину, было бы неплохо узнать как сделать частичный перенос.

Делаю следующее:

```
$ git checkout -borigin/fragments
$ git checkout -b fragments origin/fragments
```

В терминале вижу следующее:

```
> 
M       AndroidStudioProjects/TestTask/app/build.gradle
M       AndroidStudioProjects/TestTask/app/src/main/java/com/simpals/testtask/ac
M       AndroidStudioProjects/TestTask/app/src/retrofit/java/com.simpals.testtas
Switched to a new branch 'fragments'
```

Но добавление файлов никаких не вижу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начать стоит с того, что у вас на домашней машине есть несохранённые изменения. Три строки, начинающихся с М – это файлы, которые были **м**одифицированы (**m**odified) со времени последнего коммита. Сохраните эти изменения в какую-нибудь ветку, только не в `master`. Вдруг они ценные.

Похоже, что вы уже когда-то клонировали этот проект на домашнюю машину. Но на сервер вашу ветку с рабочей машины вы запушили позже, поэтому в репозитории на домашней машине соответствующих коммитов нет. Репозитории git не поддерживают какой-либо постоянной связи, подобной почтовому протоколу IMAP. Для обновления данных нужно явным образом выполнить команду:

```
git fetch origin
```

Теперь у вас появится (или обновится, если уже была) следящая ветка `origin/fragments`. Вы можете легко создать соответствующую ей локальную ветку, но только если имя ещё не занято:

```
git checkout fragments
```

При этом:
1. Создаётся локальная ветка с именем `fragments`
1. Эта ветка настраивается на push и pull в ветку `fragments` репозитория `origin`, которая у вас представлена веткой `origin/fragments`

Если вы соответствующую ветку уже создали и имя занято (это так, судя по приведённым в вопросе командам), нужно просто переставить её на новый коммит:

```
git checkout fragments
git reset origin/fragments
```

И чтобы связать её с веткой `origin/fragments`, когда будете пушить изменения, сделайте так:

```
git push -u origin fragments
```

Answer (score 0):

можно так попробывать    `git clone http://repozitoriy.git -b branch-name`

Comment: fatal: Remote branch branch-fragments not found in upstream origin

Comment: не получается склонировать ветку в проект

Comment: клонируете в папку потом нужно делать merge.

Comment: обновил вопрос, взгляните пожалуйста

Comment: @Version8 зачем потом делать merge?

Comment: @VadimMorozov вы слишком буквально поняли пример. В `branch-name` обе части - это имя ветки, а не команда. Потому и `Remote branch branch-fragments not found`, что нужно было `git clone ... fragments`, а не `git clone ... branch-fragments`